# Como desabilitar o Drawer do React Navigation em rotas específicas

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation

Olá, estou criando uma aplicação que não deve apresentar o Drawer em rotas específicas como de login, registro, etc. Atualmente meu arquivo está assim:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions'

import SplashScreen from '../../screens/SplashScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../../screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../../screens/RegisterScreen'
import LanScreen from '../../screens/LanScreen'

export default Navigator = FluidNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen, },
  RegisterScreen: { screen: RegisterScreen },
  LanScreen: { screen: LanScreen }
});
```

Preciso que o drawer só apareça na `LanScreen`. Como eu faço para configurar o Navigator para que o mesmo não apareça em determinadas telas?

> No arquivo acima estou usando a biblioteca `react-navigation-fluid-transitions` mas ela é uma extensão do `react-navigation` por isso a pergunta se encaixa para as 2 bibliotecas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar duas stacks, uma para telas que não terão o drawer e uma com o FluidNavigator:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import SplashScreen from '../../screens/SplashScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../../screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../../screens/RegisterScreen'
import LanScreen from '../../screens/LanScreen'

const DrawerNavigator = FluidNavigator({
  LanScreen: { screen: LanScreen }
});

export defaut createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen,
  LoginScreen,
  RegisterScreen,
  DrawerNavigator,
});
```